# How to use the same UI instance across different layouts in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, static, singleton

I have a UI component, say a button, that exists in multiple views in my application. I'm using a singleton approach to keep track of the state of the button. This button is placed at different locations in these different views. Right now, I'm simply introducing as many buttons in different views by doing (Button)findViewById($id_of_button). Yet, because I want this specific button to exhibit the same behavior(enabled, etc.) across different views, I was wondering if there is a way for me to create a single instance of the button and only manage that one button in my singleton object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your button in a separate layout (R.layout.universalButton), then you may include it as a child of any ViewGroup (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc)  with inflate method of LayoutInflater:

```
View button=activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.universalButton, viewGroup, false);
button.setOnClickListener(listener);
viewGroup.addView(button);
```

Also you can include it anywhere in XML with `include` statement

```
<include layout="@layout/universalButton" android:name="button1" />

<include layout="@layout/universalButton" android:name="button2" />
```

*Note that there always will be several instances of a button, because a view can have only one parent!*